# Hide selected TR using JQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have following table where each row has a unique ID. Now I want, if I click to Remove link the row ID will pass to a PHP file t remove record from MySQL DB and then selected row will just hide with JQuery magic.

```
<table id="projects_rec">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="MjY=">
      <td>Dany</td>
      <td><a onClick="remove('MjY=')" class="actions">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="MjU=">
      <td>King</td>
      <td><a onClick="remove('MjU=')" class="actions">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="MjQ=">
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td><a onClick="remove('MjQ=')" class="actions">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I wrote

```
function remove(mid){
    document.getElementById(mid).style.display='none';
}
```

but how do it pass ID to PHP file and then hide TR with SLOW effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to hide the ID by using:

`$('#'+id).hide('slow');`

assuming that your javascript function remove looks similar to this.

```
remove(id)
{
  $.ajax({
    url: url here,
    type: "POST",
    data: {id : id },
    success: function(data)
    {
        var row_id = id.toString().replace(/=/g, "\\=");
        $('#'+row_id).hide('slow');    
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("Error");
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice but with a little addition of var foo = row_id.toString().replace(/=/g, "\\=");

Comment: Good shout, I hadn't realised the ID's all had an = in them. Props to Tats_innit for noticing that. I've incorporated his suggestion into the answer.

Comment: I am using same ajax POST technique to add record but before insertion I made a check in DB if same record already exists! If it is then I echo "Already Exists" else insert. But Ajax does not show the Err message although I am using error: function(...

Comment: The error function is used if the Ajax request fails for some reason (for timeouts, 404's etc). The ajax request completes successfully and therefore calls the success: option You need to test for the item already added by doing something similar to If(data == "already added") { alert(data); }

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr id="MjQ=">
  <td>Test 2</td>
  <td><a onClick="remove('MjQ=',this)" class="actions">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

in the `remove` function

```
function remove(id,$this){
 //do the php stuff
 $.post('remove.php',{id:id},function(){
   $("#"+id).hide();
 });     
}
```

on the php end you can get the id as

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/feake/

You need to escape the character `=` in your id and in the sample demo I replaced it with escape `\\=` and Bingo it works.

This will help you! :)

**code**

```
function remove(row_id){
    var foo = row_id.toString().replace(/=/g, "\\=");

    $("#"+foo).css('display','none');

  }​
```

Comment: @MuhammadSajid Glad it helped man, :) don't forget to accept and up vote if this helps. cheerios!